# Bluetooth low energy: effect of slave latency on power consumption

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, power-consumption

Slave latency is meant to allow a bluetooth le slave to skip a certain number of connection intervals before actually establishing a connection event with the master. In principal, this seems like it should mean that increasing the slave latency should have similar impact on power consumption of the slave as increasing the connection interval (i.e. if the product of slave latency and connection interval is the same, power consumption of the slave should be roughly the same regardless of each parameter's actual value).

Ok, so I've been using nrfgo studio to try and get some power consumption estimates for different parameter's, and it looks like my assumption here is wrong. For example, a slave latency of 0 and connection interval of 500ms yields an average consumption of ~26uA, while a slave latency of 10 and connection interval of 50ms yields an average consumption of ~105uA.

Am I misunderstanding how slave latency works? Or is nrfgo accounting for slave latency in some different way? Is it possible that nrfgo is miscalculating it's estimate?

*Note: the number above are from estimates in the nrfgo studio, not measurements on actual hardware*